# Querying Assets using the Legacy ID

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, content-builder

For some reason the `_emailid` in Email Send context returns back the legacy Email ID value instead of the Asset ID. Using what data we have (and because theres no other options) I have to query the Asset ID using the `API /asset/query`.

Here is the query parameters I've tried using but haven't been successful:

```
{
  "query": {
    "property": "legacy.LegacyId",
    "simpleOperator": "equals",
    "value": "XXX"
}
```

I've tried `property:assetType.id` which has been unsuccessful and I cant use the `property:Id` as that refers to the "Asset ID", which is the value I'm trying to get.

Edit:

```
{
    "query": {
        "property": "Data.Email.LegacyData.LegacyId",
        "simpleOperator": "equals",
        "value": 16696
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the correct path might be `legacyData.LegacyId`

Comment: I tried this, doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Try the full path `Data.Email.LegacyData.LegacyId`

Comment: That didn't work either (returned no results), I have updated my original question incase the syntax is wrong.

Comment: I will try to look more into it later once I can get to a computer and see if I can find the issue

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is pretty old, but I recently ran across the same issue and had luck by querying the path data.email.legacy.legacyId.

My api call looked like /asset/v1/content/assets?$filter=data.email.legacy.legacyId eq {{legacyId}}